# All permutations of a Regular expression

Tags: regex, c++11

I want to construct a regular expression which will match all the strings which have at least one occurrence of each of character of **M, N, P, Q**  and possibly infinite occurrence of **A, C, G, T** (a few examples are MNPQA, MNAAPQ, MNPQ, MAPGNQC, etc.). One way I found is **MNPQ[ACGT]*** and get all the permutations of the result. The question is can we construct a only one regexp which will generate all the strings I want, or if that's not possible can I check also for occurrence of all the permuted regexps (first option) in a string using C++11 regexp API ?

Comment: Why are you using regex for this, you probably can probably do this is a creative way using a group and lookback, but why bother writing such a complicated regex, that you don't understand that will not be maintainable? If you don't understand the code your writing in regex how do you expect the rest of the developers to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

A regex may not be the best thing to use in this situation. It's super messy and will run slow, but, here you go. `\b[ACGT]*([MNPQ])[ACGTMNPQ]*((?!\1)[MNPQ])[ACGTMNPQ]*((?!\1|\2)[MNPQ])[ACGTMNPQ]*((?!\1|\2|\3)[MNPQ])[ACGTMNPQ]*\b`

Example shown here: https://regex101.com/r/9iwbC7/5

```
\b                    # Start of word
[ACGT]*               # Possible ACGT chars
([MNPQ])              # M,N,P or Q 
[ACGTMNPQ]*           # Filler characters
((?!\1)               # Lookahead ensures not in previous match.
[MNPQ])               # M,N,P or Q
[ACGTMNPQ]*           # Filler characters
((?!\1|\2)            # Lookahead ensures not in previous matches.
[MNPQ])               # M,N,P or Q
[ACGT]*               # Filler characters
((?!\1|\2|\3)[MNPQ])  # M,N,P, or Q but not one that happened before
[ACGTMNPQ]*           # Filler characters
\b                    # End of Word
```

Comment: oh sorry, I was mistaken. Not exactly one occurrence of M, N, P, Q rather then minimum one occurrence of each of character

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The regex matches for 1 of each M, N, Q and P. Do you want it to be one or zero of each M, N, Q, P so "MAP" would match for example?

Comment: I mean match at least one of each M N Q P, not exactly one

Comment: or it's inpossible using regexp ?

Comment: So MAP would not match but MPPQQN would?

Comment: yea, exactly   that

Comment: A lot of things are possible with Regex. I love regex puzzles so I am happy to produce a regex for most things. But, it can become unwise for many reasons. Maintainability(particularly if you don't understand the regex) and speed in particular.

Comment: I understand regexp, but it's complicated thing and I can't make a regexp for this problem. If you can, please share, if not advise another option

Comment: I've edited my original answer with a regex for my new understanding. The link should also work. My first guess at how I would do this is use a simple regex to grab all the words I might be filtering on. For example `\b[MNPQACGT]*\b` then use normal code to check if all the letters are contained in each match.

Comment: It works perfectly on the case when M N P and Q are different characters, but when they are the same this doesn't match true patterns, for example when we consider A A A A instead of M N P Q, this doesn't match AATAA